# LSTM InvalidArgumentError Tensorflow 2.0/Keras when converting to estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to build an `LSTM` network that takes in a sequence of words and convert it into an embedding vector. I've already converted each sequence of words into vocabulary vectors.

The batch size I'm using is 32 and the size of each vocabulary vector is 50. This is the Keras Functional API code I have so far to create the model and convert it to an estimator

```
input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(50,), name='search')
embedding_layer = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=32, output_dim=256, input_length=50)(input_layer)
lstm_layer = keras.layers.LSTM(units=256)(embedding_layer)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=lstm_layer)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
estimator = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)
```

But this code gives the error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Node 'Adam/gradients/lstm/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/StatefulPartitionedCall': Connecting to invalid output 5 of source node lstm/StatefulPartitionedCall which has 5 outputs
```

When I run `model.summary()`, this is the output

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
search (InputLayer)          [(None, 50)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 50, 256)           8192      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 256)               525312    
=================================================================
Total params: 533,504
Trainable params: 533,504
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

which I think is what I expect. I tried replacing the `LSTM` layer with a Dense and Flatten layer of the same shape and the code works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to answer this myself...it seems like there's problems with tf.keras.layers.LSTM as of 7/24 as seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29189). I changed the model to the following

```
input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(50,), name='search')
embedding_layer = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=32, output_dim=256, 
input_length=50)(input_layer)
lstm_layer = keras.layers.RNN(cell=keras.layers.LSTMCell(units=256))(embedding_layer)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=lstm_layer)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
estimator = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)
```